# Boy meets female version of self from alternate dimension after his mother dies

Tags: story-identification, parallel-universe

When I was young I read a book about a teenage boy whose life was very miserable because his mother had died. He then finds a girl in his house and she thinks she is in her house. They share about their life and find out that they are the same person but in different dimensions.

They realized that every decision and choice had 50/50% chance of happening. He was envious that her mother was still alive and his mother was dead.

Comment: Welcome to the site! Do you remember exactly when you read it, and whether or not it was new as the time?

Comment: To clarify, you said you read it "when I was young", but we have no idea when that was for you. If you could give us a range of years when you might have read it, that would help significantly.

Comment: The title initially made me think about the 2014 film Predestination (based on the 1959 short story 'All You Zombies'), but your further description doesn't seem to fit.

Comment: It's definitely not your answer, but this reminds me of an episode of Red Dwarf: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parallel_Universe_(Red_Dwarf)

Answer (score 24):

**A Crack in the Line** by Michael Lawrence, 2003, first book of the *Aldous Lexicon*?

**Alaric**

It's been two years since his mother died in a terrible train crash, and Alaric's life continues to unravel. He and his father are barely on speaking terms, and Withern Rise, their Victorian mansion, is in shambles. Trapped at home during a blizzard, Alaric stumbles into a parallel world; a reality in which his mother is still alive. There's only one problem ... someone else is living his life.

**Naia**

Naia tries not to dwell on the horrible accident two years ago that nearly took her mother away. Now that life with her parents in Withern Rise has returned to normal, Naia thinks the worst is behind her. But during a freak snowstorm she's confronted by a stranger. Why does this boy look like her? Why does he have the same thoughts? The same memories? Who is he?

Answer (score 5):

Don't know when you were a teenager, but vaguely seems like maybe a scene that I believe I recall from [Interworld](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/InterWorld) (2007).  But I don't have a copy handy to double check that the particular details of the alternate dimension you are describing match up.

I am certain the protagonist meets a female version of himself in his early dimension hopping.  I recall his mother was not healthy.  I recall him being envious of some of the good aspects of the alternate dimensions he visited.